# Exchange 2010 Autodiscover/OAB update issue

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, autodiscovery

Mid way through migration from 2003 to 2010 and with a few test users on 2010 i've noticed that the OAB is not being downloaded to outlook clients.

I've checked the URL's are configured, addded both our CAS servers to the web based distribution list for the OAB and assigned the OAB to 2 mailbox databases we use but when i use outlook 'Test E-Mail AutoConfiguration' test i still see that the autodiscover says "OAB URL: Public Folder" even though i've now deselected the option.

I've ran Test-OutlookWebServices to which i was getting an OAB error about no URL in the autodiscovery but having just re-ran it now appears fine, yey the autoconfigure test still does not.

Does anyone have any idea why i'm getting this discrepency?

Comment: Is the client running Outlook 2003?

Comment: No, 2010. It appears the changes have propogated overnight. However how it just hangs downloading the OAB so atleast i have something new to look into.

Comment: Try running: Get-OfflineAddressBook | Update-OfflineAddressBook -and then- Get-ClientAccessServer | Update-FileDistributionService -Type OAB

Answer (score 1):

Just resolved this issue with Microsoft support. The 3 users not receiving < OAB URL > from autodiscover.xml had a specific (and the wrong) OAB configured in their AD Object setting "msExchUseOAB", instead of being "< not set >". With the entries for "msExchUseOAB" cleared, OAB settings were obtained from Autodiscover.